# Reading the value of a "settings bundle" simple value

Tags: ios, settings, nsuserdefaults, key-value

I have a very simple setting in a setting bundle. It is just a TRUE or FALSE value set with a toggle switch. Based on that, my app should display a button or not. Simple enough.

But when I read the value, I am getting a null. I know it is set properly as I can see it in the settings app.

Here is how I read the value

```
myButton.hidden = ![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"my key"];
```

I put that line in the viewDidLoad, in the applicationDidFinishLaunching and nothing! I keep getting null.

Your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if the user has not touched the settings and you have not given any default values (in code) to your settings values, they will return as null... if you want to set "actual" defaults (so when you call them you will get some value) to the setting you must do something like (you should check that they have not been set already)..

```
NSMutableDictionary *d=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    //set the values for d
    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:d];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:dict];
    [d release];
```

hope it helps

Comment: How can we check if they have not set it before?

Comment: you should have to set them once and only once really.. if any of them give you back nil then you know it has not been set

Comment: I just realized that is setting up/reading the preference in the local app domain, not on the global domain set in the settings app. How do you change that behavior?